# Is the verb "to rob" somehow related to Robin Hood?

Tags: etymology, proper-nouns

Does the verb "to rob" come from the famous robber "Robin Hood", was that name created after the verb, or is it simply a fun coincidence?

Comment: The first name *Robin* is [a bird](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_robin), there are many even traditional names based on nature phenomenons. Think plants (Hazel, Rose, Daisy, Poppy, Willow...) seasons and similar (Dawn, Autumn, Summer), or, as in this case, birds.

Comment: @Stephie, it's interesting that while most nature-based names are almost exclusively applied to women, *Robin* is both the only common bird-derived name, and commonly male

Comment: @ChrisH while [Robin Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Wright) might disagree, you are mostly correct. In Germanic traditions, there is also "Falk" (= "Falcon") known since the middle ages for men, or the non-bird "Wolf / Wulf". "Leo" (Latin for lion) is also still very popular today, in many languages.

Comment: The name Robin does _not_ come from the bird, it's the other way round. Robin used to be a common nickname for men named Robert. In the Middle Ages many familiar birds were given human nicknames (e.g. Jenny Wren, Jack Daw) and in the case of 'Robin Redbreast', it's the human name that has stuck.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @KateBunting I read that too, shortly after writing my comment to Stephie. I wonder which way round applies to your surname!

Answer (score 1):

The Merriam-Webster's Collegiate® Dictionary

> **Etymology**:  Middle English robben, from Anglo-French rober, of Germanic origin; akin to Old High German roubōn to rob ― more at REAVE
>
> **Date:**               13th century

So I do not think it has anything to do with Robin Hood the  outlaw.

Comment: Looking up and quoting references the OP is expected to have checked is not what is required on ELU.